# Async problem at render time of React function: it will redirect directly instead of waiting for fetch to end

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I want a page to render based on token validation. If the token is valid, it renders, if not, redirects.
When I did this using a React Class there was no problem whatsoever and everything works as expected.
Now, due to my need of using a param on the URL route (the token), I need to use Hooks. React Router constrains in this matter in order to use {useParams}. This has brought unexpected async problems. This is the code.
If instead of doing a  I render some regular  it actually works fine, but I believe it is a lousy approach and would like to know the proper way to handle this so that it redirects if the token validation was incorrect and renders the right component if it was correct. Also, this is the first time I work with React fuctions instead of Components so any other tip for cleaner code will be appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    useParams, Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";


export default function ResetPassword() {

    let { token } = useParams();
    const [tokenStatus, setTokenStatus] = useState(false);

    const validateToken =  () => {
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("access-token", token);

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            redirect: 'follow'
        };

        fetch("http://localhost:4000/verifyemailtoken", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => {if (result==="Access Granted")
        {
                setTokenStatus(true);

        }})
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }

    validateToken();


    if (tokenStatus) {
        return (

            <div className="app">
                THE TOKEN WAS VALID       
            </div>
        )
    }
    else {

        return (
            <Redirect to="/home/>
 
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: You should take the business logic inside `validateToken` and put it inside of a `useEffect` hook with the `token` in the dependency array - this looks like it should be inside of a `componentDidMount` lifecycle method if it was a class-based component, since it will only have to be run once when the component mounts for the first time. As for showing appropriate things based on some state, I'd introduce a `loading` state so that you can show a `loading` indicator and then once you validate the token you either show the `component` or do the `redirect`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it looks like it will be so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you need additional `state` which would indicate that the check is running prior to showing the `the token was valid` message or redirecting users to `home`.

```
function ResetPassword() {
  const { token } = useParams();
  const [tokenCheckComplete, setTokenCheckComplete] = React.useState(false);
  const [tokenStatus, setTokenStatus] = React.useState(false);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("access-token", token);

    var requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: "follow"
    };
    
    // reset state when new token is passed
    setTokenStatus(false);
    setTokenCheckComplete(false);

    fetch("http://localhost:4000/verifyemailtoken", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => {
        if (result === "Access Granted") {
          setTokenStatus(true);
        }
        setTokenCheckComplete(true);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setTokenStatus(false);
        setTokenCheckComplete(true);
      });
  }, [token]);

  if (!tokenCheckComplete) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  return tokenStatus ? (
    <div className="app">THE TOKEN WAS VALID</div>
  ) : (
    <Redirect app="/home" />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to add an else statement to the if to make it work, with else{ setTokenStatus(false);
                    setTokenCheckComplete(true);

Comment: @CarlaAgulló inside the `then`, correct? Yes, you're right, I missed that, the `setTokenCheckComplete` should be called no matter whether access is granted or not - fixed it. Thanks.